# Get rows in sequence from multiple table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

I want to get all rows in sequence from 2 tables in SQL Server.

Output should be 1st row from 1st table, then 1st row from 2nd table,
2nd row from 1st table, 2nd row from 2nd table....etc

[image: output should be 1st row from 1st table, then 1st row from 2nd table, 2nd row from 1st table, 2nd row from 2nd table....etc]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What @eshirvana suggested will not get you the desired. Instead, it'll be table1.row1, table2.row1, table2.row2, table1.row2

You can use UNION to join data from two tables when the column names and types match. I'm making an assumption on how to order the data based on your desired outcome.

```
SELECT RowID, Row, z
FROM table1 
UNION
SELECT *
FROM table2
ORDER BY z, RowID
```

Here's the working code:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=068c0fd2056cc48718345e85b74b7bba

Comment: RowID seems to be with gaps. We cannot depend on them for ORDER BY.

Answer (score 1):

probably something like that :

```
select * from 
(
select rowID,Row,z from table1
union all
select rowID,Row,z from table2
) alltables
order by z
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below approach:

```sql
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT RowId,Row,Z,1 AS TableOrder From Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT RowId,Row,z,2 AS TableOrder From Table2
)
ORDER BY Z,TableOrder
```